# How to fix null response using JsonArrayRequest using a Get method?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting a null response when I make a call to the Get method using a `JsonArrayRequest`.

I tried both `OnResponse` and `parseNetworkResponse` override methods in the request but still the response is null.

```
String  url = "http://myUrl";
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.i("TAG",response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("on Error Response", error.toString());
    }
})
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        int statusCode = response.statusCode;
        switch (statusCode) {
            case 200:
                Log.i("TAG1", response.toString());
        }       
        return null;
    }
};
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

I am expecting to get a json array consist of three json objects

I also used  this :

```
return Response.success(response, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

still response is null.

Comment: check that your backend is working OK. Check with some tool like Postman

Comment: yes I checked the backend with insomnia and it is working I get the headers in my code same as the tool but not the Json Array and nested objects